# Limit of maximum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $\xi_n = \max\{\eta_1,···,\eta_n\}$, where $\eta_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with a distribution function $F(x) = 1−x^{−\alpha}, \alpha > 0$ for $x > 1$ and $0$ if $x \leq 1$. Let us denote by $$\zeta_n = \frac{\xi_n}{n^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$

What is the distribution of $\zeta_n$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Yeah, it's true I haven't added "something personal" to this, because I don't know how to aproach it. Don't know how to deal with the $max$ function. If it was something more simple like a sum I bet I would have already solved the problem!

Comment: Hint: For $t>0$, $\xi_n>t$ iff $\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_n>t$.

Comment: @Math1000 isn't it enough just one of the random variables to be greater than $t$, since $\xi_n$ is the maximum of them ???

Comment: Sorry, other way around; $\xi_n \leqslant t$ iff $\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_n\leqslant t$.

Comment: Also, you should have $x>1$ instead of $x>0$ in order for $F$ to be a distribution function.

Comment: So the PDF of $\xi_n$ should be $(-\alpha x ^{-\alpha - 1})^n$. Is this correct, @Math1000 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>1$, we have
$$\mathbb P(\xi_n\leqslant x) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \left\{\eta_i\leqslant x\right\}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb P\left(\eta_i\leqslant x \right) = \left(1 - x^{-\alpha}\right)^n. $$
Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\zeta_n\leqslant x) &= \mathbb P\left(\xi_n n^{-\frac1\alpha}\leqslant x\right)\\ &= \mathbb P\left(\xi_n\leqslant xn^{\frac1\alpha} \right)\\&=\left(1-\left(xn^{\frac1\alpha}\right)^{-\alpha}\right)^n\\
&= \left(1-\frac{x^{-\alpha}}n \right)^n.
\end{align}
From there the limit as $n\to\infty$ should be apparent.

Comment: So if $\gamma = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \zeta_{n}$, then $P(\gamma \leq x) = e^{x^{-\alpha}}$. Right ?

Comment: I think you're missing a $-$ there.

Comment: Ah yeah, sure! It's $P(\gamma \leq x) = e^{-x^{-\alpha}}$.

Comment: OK, thank you very much !!!